# Evaluate $\int \frac{e^{z^3}}{z^4}dz$ where $\gamma$ is simple closed curve not including $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Check if I did it correct,

$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{z^3}}{z^4}=\frac{2\pi i}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)$

Where $k=3$ and $f(z)=e^{z^3}$.

So I computes this out to being

$$\frac{\pi i}{3} (9z^6+18z^4+2)(3e^{z^3})$$

at $z=0$ this equals $2 \pi i$. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Does $\gamma$ go around $0$?

Comment: No but $0 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{\gamma\}$ where $\{\gamma\}$ is the image of $\gamma$ @subrosar

Comment: If $\gamma$ does not go around $0$ then the contour integral is $0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: Thats what /I initially thought, cause winding number is zero. @subrosar